# What is this effect called and how does one achieve it using Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am trying to generate the following "effect" from a basic shape in MATLAB:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/DkLVp.png]

But I don't even know how this process is called. Let's say I have an image containing the brown shape, what I want is generate the contours outside of it, that get smoother as they get bigger.

Is there either a name for this effect, a function to do this in MATLAB or an algorithm that does it from scratch?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`bwdist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/bwdist.html).

The image you are displaying looks like the positive part of a distance function from the boundary of your shape. You can perform this easily in Matlab using the examples on the [aforementioned manual page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/bwdist.html).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
I = imread('brown_image.png');
I_bw = (rgb2gray(I) > 0);   % or whatever, just so I_bw is 1 in the 'brown' region
r = 10;
se1 = strel('disk', r);
se2 = strel('disk', r-1);
imshow(imdilate(I_bw, se1) - imdilate(I_bw, se2))
```

Requires image processing toolbox, but the basic idea is to dilate the image twice with dilation elements that differ by 1 (or however thick you want the contours to be) and subtract the result of the smaller one from the bigger one.  You could then color them however you want.